# Hibernate + Spring Data Jpa: the best way to save entity with one-to-many relationship

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I've got two entities and I'm using bidirectional association.

Company Branch:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "COMPANY_BRANCH")
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class CompanyBranch {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "companyBranch", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
private Set<Department> departments = new HashSet<>();

public void addDepartment(Department department) {
    this.departments.add(department);
    department.setCompanyBranch(this);
}

public void removeDepartment(Department department) {
    department.setCompanyBranch(null);
    departments.remove(department);
}
```

Department:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "DEPARTMENT")
@Getter
@Setter
public class Department {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "COMPANY_BRANCH_ID")
    private CompanyBranch companyBranch;

}
```

I know that it is a good practise to use bidirectional association because it can associate entities on code level (if I am getting everything right). So I've got a question: how to save department entity right? Right now I'm saving it like this:

```
public Department createDepartment(Department department) {
        Department departmentFromDB = findDepartmentByNameOrPhone(department.getDepartmentName(),
                department.getPhoneNumber());

        if (departmentFromDB != null) {
            throw new ResourceAlreadyExistsException("Error message");
        }

        return departmentRepository.saveAndFlush(department);
    }
```

But am I not using addDepartment from CompanyBranch entity class, is this okay? Or should I find a CompanyBranch and invoke its method to get association on code level and after this I should save updated company branch? In code I think it will look like this:

Code in controller:

```
Department department = departmentMapper.toEntity(departmentDTO);
        CompanyBranch companyBranch = companyBranchService.getCompanyBranchById(companyBranchId);
        departmentService.createDepartment(department, companyBranch);
```

Code in department service

```
public void createDepartment(Department department, CompanyBranch companyBranch) {
        Department departmentFromDB = findDepartmentByNameOrPhone(department.getDepartmentName(),
                department.getPhoneNumber());

        if (departmentFromDB != null) {
            throw new ResourceAlreadyExistsException("Отдел с таким названием или номером телефона уже существует");
        }

        companyBranchService.addDepartment(companyBranch, department);
    }
```

`addDepartment` method in `CompanyBranch` service:

```
public void addDepartment(CompanyBranch companyBranch, Department department) {
        companyBranch.addDepartment(department);
        companyBranchRepository.saveAndFlush(companyBranch);
    }
```

In that way I will maintain bidirectional association between classes, but hibernate needs to generate more queries (for example I need additional query to get Company Branch). Is it a good practise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your purpose is just for inserting a new `Department` to DB , what you are doing is already enough. The reasons are :

1. You never need to get the `departments` from the `CompanyBranch` after you create a new `Department` for doing some logic.
2. The value in the `CompanyBranch.departments` field will not be considered by JPA to determine what FK values are generated for the insert Department SQL as you are now configure it as `mappedBy`

Because of these , why need to bother to maintain the `CompanyBranch.departments` fields to have correct state as what values are they will not affect the application ?

Comment: So that means that it is better not to use collection in my application at all? In that case, when should i really use the collection and when will the fields in `CompanyBranch.departments` affect the application?

Comment: depend on your use cases . if you want to create a Department via CompanyBranch , or want to query Department with its CompanyBranch , you need to map `CompanyBranch.departments`. But in this question which your case is to only create a Department without via Department , it is not necessary to map `CompanyBranch.departments`

Comment: i mean create a Department without via CompanyBranch